# Need help with Postfix canonical mapping

Tags: server, email, postfix

I’m having difficulty getting the `canonical_maps` function to work as needed to repair some incorrect addresses from a legacy client.  Here’s the situation and what I’ve tried so far:

Legacy client (oldhost.legacy.org) does not append its domain (legacy.org) to addresses in the envelope or the message when sending them via SMTP.  So, if the user types an address such as `guser@oldhost`, it goes out with SMTP as `user@oldhost` instead of `user@oldhost.legacy.org`.

The machine with postfix (`newhost.standard.org`) has a different domain (`standard.org`) from the legacy machine.  It also acts as MX and relay for the `oldhost.legacy.org` domain.

When messages from the legacy client arrive at the postfix machine with addresses such as  `guser@oldhost` (missing `.legacy.org`),  I’d like to rewrite those to read `user@oldhost.legacy.org` .  It’s my understanding that the canonical_maps function is intended for this purpose.

In `/etc/postfix/canonical.pcre` I have:

```
/^(.*)@oldhost$/    $1@oldhost.legacy.org
```

If I test with:  `postmap –q`guser@oldhost`pcre:/etc/postfix/canonical.pcre`

the answer is:  `user@oldhost.legacy.org`.  Perfect.

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I have

```
canonical_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/canonical.pcre
```

Then, on the legacy host, I send a message such as:

```
To:  user@someotherhost.domain
Cc: user@oldhost
```

The message arrives at the postfix machine, but the CC line is not rewritten.

The documentation for canonical_maps says that in order for the headers to be rewritten, the client needs to either match the `local_header_rewrite_clients` or else the `remote_header_rewrite_domain` must be non-null.  I tried both but neither produces the output that I need.

If I set `local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all` or `permit_mynetworks` or some other option that would cause a match of the legacy client, then the `append_dot_domain` option takes over and rewrites the address as `user@oldhost.standard.org`.  The canonical table is apparently ignored.

If I instead leave `local_header_rewrite_clients` at its default (which does not match the legacy client) and turn on `remote_header_rewrite_domain = invalid.domain`, then the address is rewritten as `user@oldhost.invalid.domain` and, once again, the canonical table is apparently ignored.

So the documentation for the canonical table is correct that rewriting only occurs if the `local_header_rewrite_clients` matches the client or if `remote_header_rewrite_domain` is set.  And the rewrites are indeed occurring.  But the rewriting that takes place completely ignores the canonical table.

So how do I get postfix to apply the `append_dot_domain` and `append_at_myorigin` only to itself and apply the canonical table to other clients or, at least apply the canonical table first?